# How do you get a ddl into postgres

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have SQL Power Architect with forward engineer I created a database ERD there and then forward engineered it into a DDL file Now I need to create the Data base with it in Postgresql using PGAdmin I suppose.  I haven't a clue as to how to do that. All I have been able to find is a command line statement.
I know so little about all of this I am not sure if this is a schema or a script or how to get it to work.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
I don't see why this is so hard to get any clear information about it.  I suppose it once again is for all of those who already know.I get a lot of how to generate a DDL in Postgres and a lot of other definitions of what a DDL is nothing on what to do if you have a DDL file and want to use it to create various databases.

Comment: Can't you just convert it (save as or export) to standard SQL?

Comment: Is it an SQL script? If so, run it with `psql`

Comment: What command line statement did you find? What happened when you ran it?

Answer (score 1):

The Data Definition Language is a subset of SQL that is used to define objects such base tables, views and so on.

Start with an empty PostgreSQL database called `my_database`. If your database needs a password, [create a password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-pgpass.html). To create the objects, assuming your username is `db_user`, just redirect your DDL file called `data_definitions.sql` to the `psql` command, like this:

```sh
psql -U db_user -d my_database < data_definitions.sql
```

If you are unable to authenticate with your database, ask the person who created the database for your credentials, and look at psql's documentation with [`man 1 psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-pgpass.html) for this or other trouble with the command.